# What is 'Total execution time' measured in, in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I'm running a query in SQL Server Management Studio, including 'Client Statistics'.

I'm getting a value of '507.0000' for the 'Total execution time' in the Client Statistics. What is this value measured in? (seconds, milliseconds etc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

milliseconds, it seems.

[source from social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/edafe533-4d56-4d82-b654-9601d356675b)

#### 3rd party Edit

Added a quote from the source in case it gets lost

> What is the unit of the numbers you get in the Time Statistics-part
>   when running a query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with
>   Client Statistics turned on?

and the reply

> Surprsingly theres not alot about the client stats in BOL but I did
>   manage to find this via MSDN online. Those values are usually in MS
>   fyi.
>
> Client statistics are useful in determining how much time the network
>   and client components contribute to the total response time of a
>   query. Management Studio supports collecting Client Statistics from
>   the SQL Editor Toolbar as well as from the Query menu. Client
>   Statistics in SQL Server 2005 Beta 2 Management Studio gives you much
>   more control over client-side statistics, by giving you the option to
>   reset them, as well as displaying trial runs resulting in the average
>   values. You can use Shift+Alt+S to set client statistics on, or choose
>   the same option from the Query menu, from which you can reset client
>   statistics. Each trial result is listed in the output, along with the
>   average results over all trials. A new client statistic, total
>   execution time, is added to Time Statistics.

Another reply was

> You can try yourself by using `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'` as a query
>   and see the results in the clientstatistics